# Add InApp Purchase with Update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have a question. My App in the Store is not free. Now i will add a InAppPurchase with a Update. My App is now free with InAppPruchase. Is this App for the users they bought before this update now free? The Users can now "RePurchase" the app?

thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

If you add an in app purchase and switch the app to free, previous users will have to pay for the in app purchase unless you setup someway to tell that they came from the paid version.

Basically, unless you built logic to distinguish between customers from the paid version and just auto unlocked the in app purchase content for them, they will have to pay for the in app purchase.

Comment: Ok, thanks. When i create an update without inApp Purchase and save a Key in Userdefaults that the user have success bought the app. Now a new Update with inApp Purchase, than check the Key. Only new users must buy the InApp Items. The next question: After the Update read the NSUserDefaults, when they are saved?

Comment: And the case Restoring purchases for this problem? Apple knows that this app from user bought. Is this the solution?

Comment: I am not sure that apple will distinguish if I paid for the app or not.  Even when it is free I bought the app, how else would I own it?

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution. If you have saved anything in user defaults, than check this. If the user defaults empty than must the user purchase. If not empty than is this an update.